# How to make python argcomplete run with PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to see if I can use argument autocompletion in Windows Powershell for my python script. Powershell allegedly supports argument completion.

Here's a minimal example which does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK


import argparse
import argcomplete
from argcomplete.completers import EnvironCompleter


def argument_parser() -> argparse.ArgumentParser:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Minimal app where arcomplete should work")
    parser.add_argument("--version", action="store_true", help="print out version").completer = EnvironCompleter
    parser.add_argument("--do-this", action="store_true", help="do this").completer = EnvironCompleter
    parser.add_argument("--do-that", action="store_true", help="do that").completer = EnvironCompleter
    return parser


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argument_parser()
    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
    cli_args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then in Powershell I try: to type `python -i minimal -` and then press `<TAB>`, Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should mention that I did not enable global autocompletion. Somehow when I run `activate-global-python-argcomplete` in powershell, I get an "Open With ..." dialogue.

Comment: PowerShell only supports argument completion for PowerShell cmdlets or advanced functions/scripts. It has no way of knowing what the allowed arguments are for external commands, such as the python interpreter, and doubly so for any scripts executed by the python interpreter.

Comment: Ok, I guess then this one will be an unsolved problem. How about Windows Terminal? Does that support argument completion?

Comment: Don't know about Windows Terminal - but you can actually "hack" around the deficiency by writing a PowerShell wrapper for your python script where PowerShell does the argument processing and then passes the result to python.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that seems to be the way to work around it. Make a python binary and a custom PS wrapper.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I wonder would it be possible to somehow declare the param block objects with a python function?  then it could be wrapped dynamically

Comment: @openCivilisation I have eventually got it working with a wrapper, but damn those hours I had to spend on it. Hang on a day or two, I will assemble a minimal working example and post it here. It's something I currently use in every new project, so I might put it together as a project starting template.

Comment: I just discovered a Python app called typer, which looks like it can solve the problem.  It can install arg completion into the shell.

Comment: @openCivilisation typer looks cool and super-easy to use. However, it currently does not support mutually exclusive argument groups (but there is a workaround (typer issue #140). I shall try typer in some side projects first. Sad story: I once shot myself in the knee by adopting loguru as my logging library, and later, when I was using `behave` to automate some testcases which used my program, it just totally messed up behave's regular logging output and I also could not access my app's loguru logs in the test case' code. Since then I'm super-careful with things which look too good to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you just need a wrapper script and mind the correct encoding

```
    parser = argument_parser()
    output_stream = None
    if "_ARGCOMPLETE_POWERSHELL" in os.environ:
        output_stream = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.buffer)
    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser, output_stream=output_stream)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

I have composed a [minimal working example](https://github.com/Nagidal/powershell-argcomplete-mwe/). It's based on [Tibor's mat example](https://github.com/tibortakacs/powershell-argcomplete), but that one is actually not working because it is missing the utf-8 encoding of the buffer.